# When I start rails server, it does not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Sqlite3. It's running fine, but I need to run MySQL and then add:

1. MySQL gem
2. bundle install
3. running rails server

and I'm running into the following error:

```
es_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:29
1:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25
5:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:66
1:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25
5:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:29
1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/
connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/
abstract/connection_pool.rb:952:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.
rb:60:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `b
lock (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
:71:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
:71:in `block in execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport- (etc....)
```

My gemfile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAxru.jpg

**Development.yml:**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  reconnect: false
  database: employee_management_system
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: is it the full stacktrace?

Comment: @ray what is strat

Comment: @mrzasa and ray What i do?please explain me i am beginner

Comment: Please paste the whole stacktrace, with actual error message. It should be above of what you pasted here

Comment: @mrzasa https://imgur.com/a/jO5Apfd

Comment: the actual error is cut, increase the buffer size in your console and scroll up

Comment: @mrzasa this is my console error https://textuploader.com/1s8zu please check this link

Comment: what is above the line         from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_featur?

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **A screenshot can’t be run as code.**

Comment: @divya The really important line is not in the error messages you've shown here or in that link. The parts _before_ the bit you've shown here is *very* important. You need to get the top part of the error and add it to your question. Otherwise no-one has any information about what is going wrong.